# How to get a looping program in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming and I wanted to try to make a calculator. I made the code, but the only problem is that it will only run once. I was wondering if there was any way to get it to "loop". By that I mean, add a question to go to the beginning of the main method that way I can run the calculator again. Here is the code I have...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculatorFull {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int op;
        double num1, num2;
        Scanner operation = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1 - Add\n2 - Subtract\n3 - Multiply\n4 - Divide");
        System.out.print("Which operation would you like to perform?   ");
        op = operation.nextInt();

        if((op != 1) && (op != 2) && (op != 3) && (op != 4)){
            System.out.println("That wasn't an option...");
        }else{
            System.out.print("First number:   ");
            num1 = operation.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Second number:   ");
            num2 = operation.nextDouble();


            if(op==1){
                Add(num1, num2);
            }else if(op==2){
                Sub(num1, num2);
            }else if(op==3){
                Mult(num1, num2);
            }else if(op==4){
                Div(num1, num2);
            }
    }
}

public static void Add(double x, double y){
        double numsum;
        numsum = x + y;
        System.out.printf("%s + %s = %s", x, y, numsum);
    }

    public static void Sub(double x, double y){
        double numsum;
        numsum = x - y;
        System.out.printf("%s - %s = %s", x, y, numsum);
    }

    public static void Mult(double x, double y){
        double numsum;
        numsum = x * y;
        System.out.printf("%s * %s = %s", x, y, numsum);
    }

    public static void Div(double x, double y){
        double numsum;
        numsum = x / y;
        System.out.printf("%s / %s = %s", x, y, numsum);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Btw, I think this might be different from this question ([User input to repeat program in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367626/user-input-to-repeat-program-in-java)). I have different methods that I call from and that was changed to call from the main to just 1 method. Don't know if that changes any of the solutions or if it is the same problem but thank you for pointing out that it might be.

Comment: check out  the `for` loop and the `while` loop.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User input to repeat program in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367626/user-input-to-repeat-program-in-java)

Comment: Also note that in Java you usually start method names with lower letters:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: The best way to start a language is to read tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a sentinel value to exit the program (i.e., -1 in your option) and keep track of a variable that we will constantly check in a while loop. If op ever becomes -1, it exits. Otherwise, it will restart the logic inside the while loop.

```
    int op = 0;
    while(op != -1) {
        double num1, num2;
        Scanner operation = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1 - Add\n2 - Subtract\n3 - Multiply\n4 - Divide");
        System.out.print("Which operation would you like to perform?   ");
        op = operation.nextInt();

        if((op != 1) && (op != 2) && (op != 3) && (op != 4)){
            System.out.println("That wasn't an option...");
        }else{
            System.out.print("First number:   ");
            num1 = operation.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Second number:   ");
            num2 = operation.nextDouble();


            if(op==1){
                Add(num1, num2);
            }else if(op==2){
                Sub(num1, num2);
            }else if(op==3){
                Mult(num1, num2);
            }else if(op==4){
                Div(num1, num2);
            }
    }
```

Comment: @bh34e5 Glad to help :) If this helped you out, I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer. Have a great day :)

Comment: When I do it, it says that op hasn't been initialized yet

Comment: @bh34e5 Correction: Java warns you that it's not initialized because local variables do not get an initial value. My bad.

Comment: @bh34e5 You just need to assign the op value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int continue = 0;

while(continue == 0){
  // Put your calculator code here
  System.out.println("Enter 1 to exit or 0 to continue");
  choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

}
```

Try this.

UPDATE:

Use this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class StackOverFlow
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
    int cont = 0;

    while(cont == 0){
     System.out.println("Inside");
    // Put your calculator code here
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to exit or 0 to continue");
    cont = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

}
    System.out.println("Outside");
  }
}
```

Comment: You should try that too, before posting that as an answer.

Comment: This infinitely loops

Comment: @Tom Thanks for pointing out. I took it lightly and just answered it directly.

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb No it won't loop infinitely. It won't even compile at first place and that's what Tom pointed. Infinite loop won't be the case.

Comment: Well, your first code has an infinite loop (let's assume `continue` is a valid name), because you never update this variable. I would suggest to delete the first code, because it won't work anyway.

Comment: @PrakharVerma I assumed that you had your variable initialized and that we had the appropriate class structure surrounding it. Pseudo code usually doesn't compile.

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb There is no pseudo code in this answer.

Comment: @Tom I was under the impression that pseudocode included fragmented bits of code, as in the case where you include a code snippet without class declarations. Human interpretable, but not machine interpretable. At least that's what the definition of pseudocode seems to be according to a few different websites.

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb It wouldn't be pseudo code if it actually contains code ;P, even broken code. Pseudo code is more a descriptive language for a program flow, like "loop while variable is 0 -> print "input number" -> read user input into variable" (just image a line break for each "->", because I can't write line breaks here :D). This is also programming language independent, not like the first code block in this answer.

Comment: @Tom You are right, and an upvote to you for that. What I guess I should have said from the beginning is code snippets don't compile. Was unfairly ideating code snippets as a subset of pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this, is to just call the main method when the calculation is complete and printed. You can achieve this by using `main(null)`. Just add it right after your if-else block. Code below:

```
        if(op==1){
            Add(num1, num2);
        }else if(op==2){
            Sub(num1, num2);
        }else if(op==3){
            Mult(num1, num2);
        }else if(op==4){
            Div(num1, num2);
        }
        System.out.println(); // prints blank line
        main(null);// calls main method (re-runs program)
```

This will complete the operation, then repeat the process.

Comment: That's very helpful. I know in batch programming there is a way to get that to happen, you would just say "goto main" but I didn't think there was a way to do that in java. This is just that. Thanks for the response!